# AWS ElasticBeanstalk + Socket.IO + SSL issue

Tags: node.js, ssl, websocket, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having trouble working with AWS ElasticBeanstalk with NodeJS environment + Socket.IO + SSL for our messaging app.

I'm already running in circles trying to fix the issue but I always ends up to a Websocket handshake error (504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT).

---

**AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer configuration:**

[image: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load Balancer configuration]

---

**ELB security inbound rule**

[image: ELB security inbound rule]

---

**Instance's security inbound rule**

[image: Instance's security inbound rule]

---

**Response error**

[image]

---

**Front end code**

[image]

Thanks in advance. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Finally!!! Got it!

So after a lot of hours burned, this [solution](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1846#issuecomment-61038664) works for me.

The problem is that I have **HTTPS** in my load balancer pointed to **HTTP** on my ec2 instance. That causes a problem because websocket runs on **TCP** and not **HTTP/S**. The port number also did matter in my case.

---

**Original config (not-working)**

[image]

---

**New config (working)**

[image]

I hope this can be of any help in the future. :-)

Comment: Are the differences in the InstancePort (80 for TCP and 8080 for SSL) intended? If not, what is the reason behind it?

Comment: @Aldee i have the same certificate setup for making networking calls to API and socket also(load balancer).So, if I change it to SSL , all my network calls fails as it is looking for https and moreover, for socket server is listening to 8080 . Do i need to change it to listen to 443? Any suggestion?

Comment: bro you just saved me A LOT of headache, glad i found this right away, also had the LB set up as HTTP/HTTPS and changing it to TCP fixed it :D